# How can I apologize for a deleted question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I had posted a question, and five minutes later had found that the problem was not a real one, and had deleted the post. But somebody could already have read the post and spent some time working on the problem. ***How can I bring my excuses to them?*** I had deleted the post and of course, I cannot write an excusing comment even for people who see the deleted posts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write a comment after undeleting it and then delete it again.

#### But the more good way is,

undelete it and then edit the question and add something like this.

> #### UPDATE
>
> This is a small issue with my side and not a real problem. So, I am deleting this because it has no value here. Thanks for everyone for your time. I am sorry if anyone put some effort on it. But the Quality of site is more important.

Then delete it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use your piece of text :-)

Comment: I wouldn't edit it, I would add a comment. People who can see deleted questions can see comments on them too.

Comment: Crap like this doesn't belong in a question body, even if it is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It's water under the bridge. Just let it be.